# Error: Could not find or load main class org.h2.tools.RunScript

Tags: database, docker, h2

I have my webapplication and h2database as a docker containers. I have docker compose yml file all set. Now, i need to initialize this database ( h2database). But i am unable to do so. When i go inside h2database docker container, i see  docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/initdb.sh inside this initdb.sh i have added my script

```
#!/bin/bash
java -cp  h2-1.4.190.jar org.h2.tools.RunScript \
          -script /App1/BasePl/sql-scripts/h2/common-scripts/BasePl-schema-h2.sql \ -url "jdbc:h2:http://localhost/code1/Demo2./BasePl"
```

but when i try to execute this initdb.sh using bash command it gives me error : Could not find or load main class org.h2.tools.RunScript

I have tried all possible class path combinations and also downloaded different h2 jarfiles zip folders and also checked for RunScript file under h2\src\main\org\h2\tools and its there. So i do not understand what is the issue here.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.h2.tools.RunScript
```

my Docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  baseplapplication:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
        BASEPL_HOME: "/usr/local/BASEPL"  

    ports:
      - "882:8080"
    volumes: 
      - basepl_data:/var/bio
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
  db:
    image: "buildo/h2database"
         
    volumes:
      - ./dumps/init.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/initdb.sh    
      - h2data:/var/lib/h2database
  
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
volumes:
        basepl_data:
        h2data:
```

now the initdb will be created when i run docker-compose command and thus i need to go inside the database(db) container to the location of initdb.sh and then put my script  #!/bin/bash
java -cp  h2-1.4.190.jar org.h2.tools.RunScript 
-script /App1/BasePl/sql-scripts/h2/common-scripts/BasePl-schema-h2.sql \ -url "jdbc:h2:http://localhost/code1/Demo2./BasePl"  . How could i then put my h2-1.4.190.jar file which is located on my desktop to that location inside the database(db) container. All i want is to populate (initialize) the docker database by running a script against it during docker compose. Please i am new to docker so help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error means java did not find `h2-1.4.190.jar`.

First, you need to put `h2-1.4.190.jar` in the same folder of `initdb.sh`, that is `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` in your case. Then, in your `Dockerfile`, the `WORKDIR` I guess is not `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`.

Then, when do `java -cp h2-1.4.190.jar`, it intends to find the jar in `WORKDIR`, not in `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. E.g. if `WORKDIR` is `/root/`, then it will try to find `h2-1.4.190.jar` in `/root`, not in the folder store the script, so you can not find the jar.

To overcome this, you can change `WORKDIR` in dockerfile, or just add next to `init.db.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=$(dirname "$0")
java -cp "$dir/h2-1.4.190.jar" org.h2.tools.RunScript \
      -script /App1/BasePl/sql-scripts/h2/common-scripts/BasePl-schema-h2.sql \ -url "jdbc:h2:http://localhost/code1/Demo2./BasePl"
```

The `dir=$(dirname "$0")` will assure it's the same folder of current running script, not the folder where to start the script.

Also, you can use absolute dir for `h2-1.4.190.jar`, it's also ok.

Comment: hello atline, could you please elaborate more on your comment "The dir=$(dirname "$0") will assure it's the same folder of current running script, not the folder where to start the script." I did not understand it completely.

Comment: `java -cp h2-1.4.190.jar` is same with `java -cp ./h2-1.4.190.jar`. While `./` in above means the directory where you start run the script. Suppose `test.sh` has the contents `java -cp h2-1.4.190.jar`, and the `test.sh` in the folder `/abc/def`, then if run the script in `def folder`, then `./` means the folder `def`, but if run the script in `/abc folder` with `def/test.sh`, then the `./` means the folder `abc`. But if add `dir=$(dirname "$0")` to the perfix of `test.sh`, then no matter where you start the script, it will always means to find thing in the folder `def`.

Comment: Or you can reference the dockerfile of baseimage, use absolute path to specify `h2-1.4.199.jar`, https://hub.docker.com/r/buildo/h2database/dockerfile

Comment: thanks atline for explaining in a nice way, i have  resolved the issue now

Comment: hello i have  a problem can you help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69176341/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-h2-tools-console