# Could not find or load main class org.h2.tools.Console

Tags: wildfly, keycloak, h2

I want to connect to h2 console. I have build the code source of keycloak and now I'm under bin repository and i taped the following  command

> java -cp jar org.h2.tools.Console -url "$url" -user sa -password ""

to connect to h2 console but I get the following error

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.h2.tools.Console
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.tools.Console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use this approach instead, it should resolve the resolution of the class:

```
java -cp h2-1.4.200.jar org.h2.tools.Console
```

This would launch the console. Please adapt accordingly with regards to the directory you're launching java from.

Please keep in mind the console requires you to enter credentials in the console webapp.